# run c# program after a particular program closes

Tags: c#

I have a c# project that I am working on and in this program it launches another (.exe) program. What I want to do is watch for when that program closes and when it does run code a certain function. Is this possible? Below is my code I'm using to launch the external program.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Temporary\SOS.exe");`

Comment: `Process.Exited` event?

Answer (score 1):

Listen for the Process.Exited event.  In the event handler, call your function.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited(v=vs.110).aspx